# CSS3 slideshow navigation with :target selector?

Tags: html, css, animation, navigation, target

I've made a simple slideshow consisting of 4 videos that play on a loop. I have tried to integrate some jQuery navigation to it but I'm having an issue with the fact that the .animate to the next/prev slide isn't animating. I believe this is because you cannot apply .animate and have a css3 animation on the same element.

After researching extensively I think that this might be able to be achieved with the :target pseudo element but I'm a bit stuck with where to start. I wondered if someone could either point me in the right direction or give me some guidance?

The current setup looks like this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/akZ48/1/)

**UPDATE***
I came across this [link](http://www.designmadeingermany.de/slideshow/) and thought maybe I could integrate something like this into my current slideshow however I can't seem to get it working. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/akZ48/7/)

CSS

```
@-webkit-keyframes slider {
    0%, 20%, 100%{ left: 0 }
    25%, 45%{ left: -100% }
    50%, 70%{ left: -200% }
    75%, 95%{ left: -300% }
}

@-moz-keyframes slider {
    0%, 20%, 100%{ left: 0 }
    25%, 45%{ left: -100% }
    50%, 70%{ left: -200% }
    75%, 95%{ left: -300% }
}

@keyframes slider {
    0%, 20%, 100%{ left: 0 }
    25%, 45%{ left: -100% }
    50%, 70%{ left: -200% }
    75%, 95%{ left: -300% }
 }

#carousel .video-list {
    position: relative;
    width: 400%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0; 
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    animation: slider 65s cubic-bezier(.93,.11,.32,.94) infinite;
    -webkit-animation: slider 65s cubic-bezier(.93,.11,.32,.94) infinite;
    -moz-animation: slider 65s cubic-bezier(.93,.11,.32,.94) infinite;
    -o-animation: slider 65s cubic-bezier(.93,.11,.32,.94) infinite;
    -ms-animation: slider 65s cubic-bezier(.93,.11,.32,.94) infinite;
}
```

Comment: :target is not a pseudo-element; it's a pseudo-selector.  I don't think it does what you think it does.  Please see details here: http://css-tricks.com/on-target/

Comment: Oh right, just through researching I'm sure I've seen people use it to navigate to a slide within the reel and slide in the process I just couldn't work out how.

Comment: can you paste some links to where you've seen this done?

Comment: I've just read somewhere that you shouldn't use it. Maybe there is a better way of doing it. Do you have any suggestions? Anything I could try?

Comment: Heres an example using numbers http://chris-spittles.co.uk/pure-css3-image-slider/

Comment: have you tried google? it's first thing: http://css-tricks.com/on-target/

Comment: Hey yes I have seen that and I found the link (see update) which uses it for the purpose I think i need. I'm now struggling to get it working.